# Vim(script) - quotes in strings when used as expressions

Tags: vim

I'm trying to do the following:

```
:put = 'a string with "quotes"'
```

But I get:

```
Missing quote:  'a string
Invalid expression:  'a string
```

I can get around this:

```
:let s:var = 'a "var"'
:put = s:var
```

By reading `:h :put`, I found out that `put`, when followed by `=`, expects an *expression*. I don't know if this is the problem though, I thought strings **were** expressions (being values) like in many other languages.

**Note** this doesn't work either:

```
:put = "a string \"with quotes\""
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The key to understanding this peculiarity can indeed be found at `:help :put`:

> You need to escape the '|' and '"'
>   characters to prevent them from terminating the
>   command.

Apparently, the unescaped `"` would terminate the expression (and presumably start a comment). Therefore, escaping works:

```
:put = 'a string with \"quotes\"'
```

You can also circumvent this by using (doubled) single quotes:

```
:put ='a string with ''quotes'''
```

If you want to use double quotes, they all need escaping, and the inner once twice:

```
:put = \"a string with \\"quotes\\"\"
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I played a bit with escaping `|` and `"` on the command line but missed this. Great!

Comment: Thanks a lot @ingo-karkat . However could you explain why do we need to escape enclosing double quotes (and thus twice for the inner ones) ? Why can't we simply just escape the inner ones once like with single quotes or in simple bash ?

Comment: @adamency I guess we have to live with this peculiarity due to backwards compatibility. There are several other commands that take a `|` as part of its arguments, not as a command separator, and the `"` usually isn't a problem at all. But changing it now would break existing mappings and plugins, and introducing a new `:putEx` command just for this little nuisance isn't worth it.